# How to close window as if by using X bottom on top of window? the associated "destroy" must be called

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have two `GtkWindow`s, when a button is clicked the window1 must free all object inside on it and close, but calling the associated-function  with the `destroy` event. `gtk_main_quit()` can't be used, it doesn't call associated-function with `destroy` event. I have tried `gtk_widget_destroy()` but I get the error message(at run-time) from gtk:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET
>   (widget)' failed

Googling I found `gtk_signal_emit_by_name()` looks like be really what I need, but isn't available on GTK3+, that I'm using.

Comment: gtk_signal_emit_by_name is deprecated, use g_signal_emit_by_name instead

Comment: Thanks very much. How do I get `instance`?

Comment: I can't check it but you can try g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy");

Comment: post it as answer for I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy");`

It works?